# How to set the cursor position when dynamically mounting CK Editor 5

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I want to mount CKEditor 5 dynamically, because there will be many editors in my project

When I was dynamically loading cke, I found that the position of the cursor was incorrect

I knew how to set the cursor position of cke, but I didn’t know how to get the index and offset

```
editor.model.change((writer) => {
  const root = editor.model.document.getRoot();
  const range = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstRange();
  if (!root || !range) return;
  const nodes = Array.from(root.getChildren());
  const newPosition = writer.createPositionAt(nodes[1], 2); // how to get the index `1` and offset `2`
  const newRange = writer.createRange(newPosition);
  writer.setSelection(newRange);
});
```

How to set the cursor position to the CKEditor 5 according to the position of the mouse click?

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5v6zu1?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found two related issues on Github [issue 1](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8641) [issue 2](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/93)

At present, CKEditor 5 has not provided a good solution. I decide Initialize CKEditor 5 on mouseEnter (hover) so that the user can click on the specific word they want.